# Installing Postgis and PGRouting via pgenv

Tags: postgresql, postgis

We have a product where our production environment uses Docker and has no issue with installing things like [postgis](https://postgis.net/) and [pgrouting](https://pgrouting.org/).

However, we have multiple remote developers and many of them (including me) are using [pgenv](https://github.com/theory/pgenv) for our PostgreSQL install and I don't know how to get those extensions installed properly. The error looks like this:

```
acme_test=# create extension if not exists postgis;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/home/ovid/.pgenv/pgsql-11.5/share/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

I have several `postgis.control` files, but I don't know how to link them (or if it's safe to do so):

```
12:11:34 {spike-pgrouting-120} ~/client/acme-api $ locate postgis.control
/etc/alternatives/postgresql-12-postgis.control
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis.control
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/postgresql-12-postgis.control
```

I've installed postgis via `sudo apt-get install postgis`.

This is Postgresql 11.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.4.